# How to delete bucket life cycle rule using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using boto3. I have a to_glacier() method that creates rules in bucket's  life cycle configurations to change storage class of a particular object from standard to glacier  in some point of time.

Issue is that life cycle configuration for a bucket can have up to 1000 rules at a time. So I want to remove rules which have been applied to accommodate new rules. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and what difficulty are you facing?

Comment: It seems boto3 does not have such a call. Apparently AWS planned for lack of dynamic managing of rules and 1000 rules limit is supposed to stop us from deleting unneeded content and thus optimizing costs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading boto3 Bucket Lifecycle documentation?https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketLifecycle.delete

Comment: Yes, he did - you didn't. This method will delete *all* lifecycle rules on the bucket.